# Minecraft diamond minecart - vanilla or a resource pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have made my own dantdm lab with Grim, Dr. Trayurus, and a treasure room, but the only lacking feature is a diamond minecart.

Is there a diamond minecart in vanilla Minecraft, or is it part of a resource pack?

Comment: I believe it's a custom resource pack. Unless you want to make your own, you'll have to ask DamTDM himself or wait for someone else to make it. Alternatively, it might be a mod.

Answer (score 3):

As of 1.8, Minecraft only has iron Minecarts, and those can be either empty or loaded with Furnaces, TNT, Hoppers, Chests, Command blocks and Spawners.

Anything else comes either from a resource pack or a mod.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a resource pack. A non available feature can be only replaced by a resource pack or a mod. But if it's a mod there should be available the iron one, too.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i hope this help just download the +youtubers mod and then open with winrar archiver then open the texture pack and find the diamond minecart copy it and replace it on your texture pack and there you go now you have diamond minecart
here some pic [image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can change the mine cart texture from iron to diamond.

If you want the actual skin, you will need a mod like NPC.